# Example of n place function.

Tags: logic

I am reading now the book ["Algorithms and recursive functions"](https://books.google.it/books?id=8nOmAAAAIAAJ) of A.I.Maltsev. He writes that giving a value for the n-place functional symbol ($f_1, f_2, \text{etc.}$) means juxtaposition of partial n-place operation, defined on the main set, with this functional symbol (like mapping). Can you please show an example of 2-, 3- or more place function?

Comment: *sum* ($+$) is a $2$-place function : $+(2,3)=5$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, but what about $x^2$. Isn't it one-place function? And if I have a function of the form $f(x, y) = x*y + x + y$, can we consider it as $3$-place function?

Comment: The "places" are the number of "independent inputs" the function needs, irerspective of the "complexity" of the formula defining the function. The two formulas: $5x$ and $x+x+x+x+x$ define the same $1$-place function $f(x)$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, thank you so much! I think all above is actually an answer for the question. Combine all together and post the answer :) P.S. Can you please say, if you have red this book, how it is possible to understand it? It is full of formalization and I am new in math,  I can't actually write a proof correctly. What can you suggest me do? We use this book at university and actually study over this book. So I must read it, but I am very weak in proof writing. Is there any book or smth to learn how to prove or maybe to facilitate reading of this book?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "places" are the number of "independent inputs" the function needs, irrespective of the "complexity" of the formula defining the function.

The two formulas: $5x$ and $x+x+x+x+x$ define the same $1$-place function.

The *sum* ($+$) is a $2$-place (*binary*) function, that receives in input two numbers $n$ and $m$ and returns as output their sum $+(n,m)=n+m$.

$x^2$ is a $1$-place (*unary*) function and $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$ is a $3$-place function.

You can see e.g.: Herbert Enderton, [Computability Theory: An Introduction to Recursion Theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=y8n76ztNVlMC&pg=PA3), Academic Press (2011).